# WP Multisite Dashboard how can I change Media Space allowed?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

In a WP Multisite installation the first site shows, Media Space allowed of 35MB.

> ```
> Storage Space
>
> 35 MB Space Allowed (Manage Uploads)  
> 12.39 MB (35%) Space Used
> ```

Where is the setting to change this?
I have already tried already changing setting Max upload file size from 35000KB to 100000KB but obsviously is a different setting.

I do not have settings for file size in .user.ini o .htaccess or wp-config.php

I already have checked in CPanel taht php upload_max_filesize (MB) is set to 35MB and post_max_size (MB) also to 35MB

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I find out myself. Sorry I did not see the setting
'Site upload space'. (I suppose is for each site of the WP Multisite)